# How do I know if I have got a congestion charge?

Tags: london, fees-and-charges

I drove to Westminster Bridge Road last Wednesday around 6.45 pm. Now different people have different statements to offer. How do I know if I need to pay any fees? Help.

Answer (score 2):

The congestion charge applies between 7am – 6pm Monday to Friday except bank holidays. The fee is £11.50 per vehicle per day if you pay in advance or before midnight on the day you enter the zone, but if you forget, you can still pay the fee up to midnight the following day but the price increases to £14. After that you incur a penalty.

Westminster Bridge is in the [congestion zone](https://tfl.gov.uk/maps/congestion-charge?intcmp=40404).

Answer (score 1):

The congestion charge applies from 7am to 6pm:
https://tfl.gov.uk/modes/driving/congestion-charge

Westminster Bridge Road is definitely in the charging zone, but whether you need to pay it or not depends on what time you reached the zone.